# SQL Server 2012 Counting Semicolon separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this

```
Id FullName 
------------------- 
1 Cleo,Smith,james
```

I want result like

```
Id FullName          Count
----------------------------
1 Cleo;Smith;james     3
```

Could you please help..Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: Please, **STOP** using comma-separated values in a single cell ! This is against even the **first normal form** of database design, and makes your life miserable over and over and over again

Comment: @JonathanM.. i tried            SELECT LEN(REPLACE(myColumn, 'somevalue', '')) FROM ...

Comment: @user3617463 If you have a choice to change your schema please change it because having delimited separated values in a column will cause problems down the road.

Comment: @ZeRaTuL_jF.. Sure i'll let my seniors know about that.. THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very poor database design, but do believe you are after ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9de2d/2/0)):

```
SELECT Id, REPLACE(FullName, ',', ';') AS FullName, 
       LEN(FullName) - LEN(REPLACE(FullName, ',', '')) + 1 AS [COUNT]
FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: This worked.. but a minor change i did in your "LEN(REPLACE(FullName, ',', ''))" I replaced it with "LEN(REPLACE(FullName, ';', ''))"